# UCS-2LE text file parsing

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring, ucs2

I have a text file which was created using some Microsoft reporting tool. The text file includes the `BOM` `0xFFFE` in the beginning and then `ASCII` character output with nulls between characters (i.e "`F.i.e.l.d.1.`").  I can use `iconv` to convert this to `UTF-8` using `UCS-2LE` as an input format and `UTF-8` as an output format... it works great.

My problem is that I want to read in lines from the `UCS-2LE` file into strings and parse out the field values and then write them out to a `ASCII` text file (i.e. `Field1 Field2`).  I have tried the `string` and `wstring`-based versions of `getline` – while it reads the string from the file, functions like `substr(start, length)` do interpret the string as `8-bit` values, so the start and length values are off.

How do I read the `UCS-2LE` data into a `C++` String and extract the data values?  I have looked at `boost` and `icu` as well as numerous google searches but have not found anything that works.  What am I missing here?  Please help!

My example code looks like this:

```
wifstream srcFile;
srcFile.open(argv[1], ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
..
..
wstring  srcBuf;
..
..
while( getline(srcFile, srcBuf) )
{
    wstring field1;
    field1 = srcBuf.substr(12, 12);
    ...
    ...
}
```

So, if, for example, `srcBuf` contains "`W.e. t.h.i.n.k. i.n. g.e.n.e.r.a.l.i.t.i.e.s.`" then the `substr()` above returns "`.k. i.n. g.e`" instead of "`g.e.n.e.r.a.l.i.t.i.e.s.`".

What I want is to read in the string and process it without having to worry about the multi-byte representation.  Does anybody have an example of using `boost` (or something else) to read these strings from the file and convert them to a fixed width representation for internal use?

BTW, I am on a Mac using Eclipse and gcc.. Is it possible my `STL` does not understand wide character strings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substr works fine for me on Linux with g++ 4.3.3. The program

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  wstring s1 = L"Hello, world";
  wstring s2 = s1.substr(3,5);
  wcout << s2 << endl;
}
```

prints "lo, w" as it should.

However, the file reading probably does something different from what you expect. It converts the files from the locale encoding to wchar_t, which will cause each byte becoming its own wchar_t. I don't think the standard library supports reading UTF-16 into wchar_t.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I see the same behavior.  As you say, I don't think the UTF-16 to wchar_t is supported.  I used iconv to convert the file to UFT-8 and it solved by problem.

Comment: Although I'm probably addressing ghosts here, @Cryptik should mark his question as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Having spent some good hours tackling this question, here are my conclusions:

- Reading an `UTF-16` (or `UCS2-LE`) file is apparently manageable in C++11, see [How do I write a UTF-8 encoded string to a file in Windows, in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973582/how-do-i-write-a-utf-8-encoded-string-to-a-file-in-windows-in-c)
- Since the `boost::locale` library is now part of C++11, one can just use `codecvt_utf16` (see bullet below for eventual code samples)
- However, in older compilers (e.g. MSVC 2008), you can use `locale` and a custom `codecvt` facet/"recipe", as very nicely exemplified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208431/132735) to [Writing UTF16 to file in binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207662/writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode/)
- Alternatively, one can also try [this method](http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/reading-a-unicode-utf16-file-in-windows-c/) of reading, though it did not work in my case. The output would be missing lines which were replaced by garbage chars.

I wasn't able to get this done in my pre-C++11 compiler and had to resort to scripting it in Ruby and spawning a process (it's just in test so I think that kind of complications are ok there) to execute my task.

Hope this spares others some time, happy to help.