# How do I write a UTF-8 encoded string to a file in windows, in C++

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, file-io, utf-8

I have a string that may or may not have unicode characters in it, I am trying to write that to a file on windows. Below I have posted a sample bit of code, my problem is that when I fopen and read the values back out windows, they are all being interpreted as UTF-16 characters.

```
char* x = "Fool";
FILE* outFile = fopen( "Serialize.pef", "w+,ccs=UTF-8");
fwrite(x,strlen(x),1,outFile);
fclose(outFile);

char buffer[12];
buffer[11]=NULL;
outFile = fopen( "Serialize.pef", "r,ccs=UTF-8");
fread(buffer,1,12,outFile);
fclose(outFile);
```

The characters are also interpreted as UTF-16 if I open the file in wordpad etc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, when you specify that the text file should be encoded in UTF-8, the CRT implicitly assumes that you'll be writing Unicode text to the file.  Not doing so doesn't make sense, you wouldn't need UTF-8.  This will work proper:

```
wchar_t* x = L"Fool";
FILE* outFile = fopen( "Serialize.txt", "w+,ccs=UTF-8");
fwrite(x, wcslen(x) * sizeof(wchar_t), 1, outFile);
fclose(outFile);
```

Or:

```
char* x = "Fool";
FILE* outFile = fopen( "Serialize.txt", "w+,ccs=UTF-8");
fwprintf(outFile, L"%hs", x);
fclose(outFile);
```

Comment: Of course you'll be writing Unicode text to the file, but the point is that the CRT assumes you'll be writing **UTF-16**.

Comment: @dan - no, it assumes you'll be writing wchar_t.  That it is utf-16 on Windows is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy if you use the `C++11` standard (because there are a lot of additional includes like `"utf8"` which solves this problems forever).

But if you want to use multi-platform code with older standards, you can use this method to write with streams:

1. [Read the article about UTF converter for streams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams)
2. Add `stxutif.h` to your project from sources above
3. Open the file in ANSI mode and add the BOM to the start of a file, like this:

   ```
   std::ofstream fs;
   fs.open(filepath, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

   unsigned char smarker[3];
   smarker[0] = 0xEF;
   smarker[1] = 0xBB;
   smarker[2] = 0xBF;

   fs << smarker;
   fs.close();
   ```
4. Then open the file as `UTF` and write your content there:

   ```
   std::wofstream fs;
   fs.open(filepath, std::ios::out|std::ios::app);

   std::locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new utf8cvt<false>);
   fs.imbue(utf8_locale); 

   fs << .. // Write anything you want...
   ```

Comment: How do you do it with C++11?

Comment: why do you need the bom? I read around that it is not required or even recommended in utf-8, since it has no meaning. Is writing the bom required in windows or can be avoided entirely?