# Handling Non-Ascii Chars in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, non-ascii-characters

I am facing some issues with non-Ascii chars in C++. I have one file containg non-ascii chars which I am reading in C++ via file Handling. After reading the file(say 1.txt) I am storing the data into string stream and writing it into another file(say 2.txt).

Assume 1.txt contains:

```
ação
```

In 2.txt I should get same ouyput but non-Ascii chars are printed as their Hex value in 2.txt.

Also, I am quite sure that C++ is handling Ascii chars as Ascii only.

Please Help on how to print these chars correctly in 2.txt

EDIT:

Firstly Psuedo-Code for Whole Process:

```
1.Shell script to Read from DB one Value and stores in 11.txt
2.CPP Code(a.cpp) reading 11.txt and Writing to f.txt
```

Data Present in DB which is being read: `Instalação`

File 11.txt contains: `InstalaÃ§Ã£o`

File F.txt Contains: `InstalaÃ§Ã£o`

Ouput of a.cpp on screen: `Instalação`

a.cpp

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myReadFile;
    ofstream f2;
    myReadFile.open("11.txt");
    f2.open("f2.txt");
    string output;
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
    {
        while (!myReadFile.eof())
        {
            myReadFile >> output;
                //cout<<output;

            cout<<"\n";

            std::stringstream tempDummyLineItem;
            tempDummyLineItem <<output;
            cout<<tempDummyLineItem.str();
            f2<<tempDummyLineItem.str();
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Locale says this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: So exactly what is your question? "How do I identify ASCII characters, and print non-ASCII as hex?"

Comment: Post your actual code (the smallest sample that exhibits your problem) and then we can tell you what minimal changes have to be made.

Comment: I want to get non-ascii chars printed as non-ascii only in 2.txt and not as their hex values

Comment: @chris - Sorry but I can't post actual C++ code due to copyright issues.

Comment: @Chris-Any specific question?

Comment: @MayankJain, The posted code should be about the same length as that pseudocode. There's no way that an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of this could be copyrighted.

Comment: @Chris - Sorry..not getting you

Comment: ohh..one min will write a eqivalent code

Comment: @MayankJain Don't forget to indicate how all of the variables are declared (e.g. `int`, `char`, etc.).  And you might also indicate how the "non-Ascii" characters are encoded (Latin 1, UTF-8, etc.).

Comment: The problem is how to identify the input text coding. It could be UTF-8, but it could also be UTF-16, and in that case the way to interpret chars completely changes. Have a look at this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text.html

Comment: We still have no idea about the encoding of your files? What is it? utf8? system locale?

Comment: @MayankJain I don't think you understand the meaning of file encoding. Characters can be written to a file in many ways, the most common being utf8 followed by utf16 big/little endian. Then you have all the system locale multibyte encodings. To answer your question, we need to know the encoding of the file. Try opening it in a text editor and look for something that may tell you how it is encoded. If you wrote it yourself, but don't know the encoding, tell us how you wrote the file.

Comment: Sorry..I don't this concepts thoroughly. However, file -i in Unix gives me this inof...text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1...File is Being created by C++ File Handling Functions...Hope this is what you are searching for..

Comment: @MayankJain ok, getting somewhere. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @MayankJain Heres your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608790/c-ifstream-and-umlauts

Answer (score 3):

At least if I understand what you're after, I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string to_hex(char ch) {
    std::ostringstream b;
    b << "\\x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::setprecision(2)
        << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(ch & 0xff);
    return b.str();
}

int main(){
    // for test purposes, we'll use a stringstream for input
    std::stringstream infile("normal stuff. weird stuff:\x01\xee:back to normal");

    infile << std::noskipws;

    // copy input to output, converting non-ASCII to hex:
    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<char>(infile),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
        [](char ch) {
            return (ch >= ' ') && (ch < 127) ?
                std::string(1, ch) :
                to_hex(ch);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a utf8 issue. Since you didn't tag your question with c++11 [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams) Is an excelent article on unicode and c++ streams.

From your updated code, let me explain what is happening. You create a file stream to read your file. Internally the file stream only recognizes `chars`, until you tell it otherwise. A `char`, on most machines, can only hold 8 bits of data, but the characters in your file are using more than 8 bits. To be able to read your file correctly, you NEED to know how it is encoded. The most common encoding is UTF-8, which uses between 1 and 4 `chars` for each character.

Once you know your encoding, you can either use wifstream (for UTF-16) or `imbue()` a locale for other encodings.

Update:
If your file is ISO-88591 (from your comment above), try this.

```
wifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.imbue(std::locale("en_US.iso88591"));
myReadFile.open("11.txt");
```