# Replacing characters adds one more character

Tags: c++

I am trying to replace characters `badSymbols` to `goodSymbols` in my text file, but it adds one more character to my replacing character. For example, when I replace `'æ'` with `'c'`, I get `'Ãc'`.

This simple program reads text file line by line and replaces characters, then writes it in "fileout.txt"

```
int main()
{
    char buffer, c;
    string line, filepath;
    fstream filein, fileout;
    char badSymbols[] = {'', 'ê', '³', 'æ', '', '¹', '¿', '£', '', '³', ''};
    char goodSymbols[] = {'s', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'z', 'a', 'z', 'L', 's', 'l', ''};
    string symbol;
    size_t found;
    cout << "Podaj sciezke pliku, w którym zamienic znaki" << endl;
    cin >> filepath;
    filepath = filepath + ".txt";
    filein.open("/home/damian/jezykc++/untitled2/gared.txt", ios:: in );
    fileout.open("/home/damian/jezykc++/untitled2/fileout.txt", ios::trunc | ios::out);
    if (filein.good() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Uzyskano dostep do pliku!" << std::endl;
        while (getline(filein, line))
        {
            // buffer=line;
            //getline(filein,line);
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(badSymbols); i++)
            {
                symbol = goodSymbols[i];
                found = line.find(badSymbols[i]);
                if (found != std::string::npos)
                    line.replace(found, 1, symbol);
            }
            cout << line << endl;
            fileout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "Dostep do pliku zostal zabroniony!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ruled out problems related to encoding, wide characters?

Comment: This is almost certainly an encoding problem. Here's (just one) reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648966/handling-non-ascii-chars-in-c

Answer (score 0):

you can use file.get() instead of getline() in while. I think it would be better if you get only one character and compare it with "bad characters". in the other word, use strcmp() for converting your characters in your code!