# Read/write unicode c++

Tags: c++, file-io, encoding, utf-8, wofstream

Sadly this is the third time this week I have to post a question.

I have to write text to a file with unicode encoding (or UTF8).

This is what I do:

creating `wofstream mystream;` and then I put a `wstring` in it like this `mystream << L"hello world";`

First question: what kind of encoding the stream uses in my case?

Secondly, I want to load my new file, but how to read the lines? The `ifstream`'s `getline` is not working because the line ends up ruined obviously.

Comment: Are you reading with `wifstream` or `ifstream`?

Comment: ifstream, but thats not working. How to use wifstream then?

Comment: `wifstream inStream("FileName.txt")`. Then just use `getline(inStream, std::wstring)`

Comment: doh! Exactly the same -_- hehe. But its working now. Thanks. Now dealing with the encoding question.

Comment: Although it's kind of hidden, Boost has a [codecvt facet for UTF-8](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html) you might find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wchar_t`, the type that backs `wstream` and `wstring`, is platform dependent: 2 bytes on Windows, 4 bytes on some (all?) Linux. So you will end up writing 'Unicode', but exactly which Unicode is subject to many variables. You may write UTF32/UCS4, you may end up with UTF16/UCS2.

If you want to write using a specific, well controlled encoding (eg. UTF8, or UCS-2LE vs. UCS-2BE to control endianess) then you need something like [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). You can also use `std::locale` to [`imbue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/imbue/) a stream, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275260/105929.

Comment: Ok thanks! But I'm writing unicode and that's the most important thing. Its a schoolproject with unicode encoding as a rule.

Comment: If you stick with `wstring` and `wstream` everywhere, and use `L"string"` constants, you will write Unicode and you application will be able to read back what it write correctly. The subtleties of knowing exactly what encoding was used become an issue as soon as you have interop of any sort.

Comment: Thank you so much. The link is very helpfull. My teacher is propably making me use UTF8 after all, but for now I am happy. Thank you

Comment: @HansElsen: Keep in mind that UTF32, UTF16, UTF8, and many others are _all_ Unicode encodings.  If it must be UTF8, used a unicode library as the answer suggests.

Comment: @MooingDuck As a student I'll have to take it literally. The exact definition was: Use Unicode or UTF8 with BOM. So Unicode it is. Haha

Comment: @HansElsen: Microsoft refers to UTF16 as "Unicode" in many places, so many programmers believe that Unicode is the same as UTF16.  They're wrong, but at least we can guess that's probably what he/she means.

Answer (score 8):

By 'unicode encoding' I presume you mean UTF-16. There are actually several encodings that might be called Unicode encodings, but most people that aren't familiar with Unicode take it to mean UTF-16 (I think largely because Microsoft makes this mistake in all their documentation). My answer also assumes you're writing code for Windows and therefore that your internal data is UTF-16 stored in wchar_t strings.

---

Using a wide stream object does not imply that the file input or output will be done using wide characters. In fact, a wide stream will use a codecvt facet of the stream's locale in order to convert between the stream's character type (wchar_t) and char.

In C++11 there are a few codecvt facets you can use to do UTF-16 or UTF-8 input/output; [`codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8), [`codecvt_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16), [`codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16).

`codecvt_utf8` will convert between external UTF-8 multi-byte sequences and internal UTF-32/UCS4 or UCS2 data. `codecvt_utf16` will convert between external UTF-16 multi-byte sequences and internal UTF-32/UCS4 or UCS2 data. `codecvt_utf8_utf16` will convert between external UTF-8 multi-byte sequences and internal UTF-16 data.

There's no built-in way to convert between external UTF-16 multi-byte sequences and internal UTF-16 data, which is what you'd want when using UTF-16 encoded wchar_t strings internally and UTF-16 encoded files externally.

But since you indicated that UTF-8 output was acceptable the codecvt_utf8_utf16 facet will work well.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wofstream mystream("test.txt");
    mystream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(),
                   new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::codecvt_mode(std::consume_header|std::generate_header)>));
    mystream << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

Also note that this example sets options on the codecvt_utf8_utf16 facet to generate and read the so-called 'UTF-8 BOM'. This is a Microsoft convention for guessing at a file's encoding and is generally inappropriate on other platforms.

---

The following is irrelevant to the question at hand, but lifetime management of facets is not like most other modern C++ lifetime management.

Facets are reference counted and when the last locale that has a particular facet is destroyed, the facet is deleted, unless that has been specifically disabled by constructing the facet with a refs parameter of `1`. The above example code leaves lifetime management to the locale, and consequently looks similar to a memory leak. The code is correct, however. In terms of exception safety, the only code that can potentially run between a successful allocation and ownership of the allocated object being assumed by the locale is the expression [`std::locale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) which is declared noexcept.

Another option is to use a facet which is not managed by the locale and to simply ensure that it outlives the locale and all copies. Using a facet with static storage duration is simple, but remember to indicate that locales should not delete the facet by setting its reference count to 1.

```
static std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::codecvt_mode(std::consume_header|std::generate_header)> mycodecvt(1);
mystream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), mycodecvt));
```

If the locale only exists for a short time in a specific scope then you can use a normal, local variable. This is the same as the above but without `static`. Just make sure the locale (as well as every copy) is destroyed before the facet goes out of scope.

This is one time where a smart pointer does not make things better, because the hand-off of ownership to a smart pointer-oblivious object is tricky. You have to figure out how to manually handle exceptions that occur after the locale has received the facet and therefore has taken ownership but before the smart pointer relinquishes ownership.

Comment: By using `new` in a parameter you're going to get a memory leak - there's nothing to delete the `codecvt_utf8_utf16` object when you close the file. I know that doesn't matter for this trivial example as it will get cleaned up by the program exit, but it's sloppy and sets a bad example.

Comment: @MarkRansom The locale library is weird in this respect. Facets are reference counted and when the last locale that has a particular facet is destroyed, the facet is deleted. If you want to create a facet on the stack and pass it to a locale you have to create the facet with a positive reference count so that locales will not try to delete it.

Comment: @MarkRansom In terms of exception safety, the only expression that could throw between a successful `new` and ownership of the allocated memory being accepted by another object is `std::locale()`, and this expression is not allowed to throw. So I believe my code is correct, but you might have a point about this being bad style, because it is kind of difficult to determine if it's correct and it is not in line with modern idioms. I'll add some examples of alternatives.