# C++ reading from a non-English filename and a non-English text

Tags: c++, unicode, io, stream

I got a file which has a non-English name. The content is also non-English.

Now, I would like to create a stream on that file to be able to read/write data.

Also, if possible, I would like to detect on which language is the text.

For example:

I have a file "հայերեն.txt" and inside the text file we have written "Բարև"․ File is Unicode-encoded. Now I want to read both filename and text into RAM.

Also, suppose I have some other text "Վահագն". Now I want to create a file "Վահագն․txt" and write some other unicode text inside the file.

OS: Windows 7+.

C++: vc120 or vc140.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean, non-english? Do you mean it's in UTF8? You can usually just create a stream from the file using ifstream, but you need to be careful when interpreting the bytes.

Comment: [How to open an std::fstream (ofstream or ifstream) with a unicode filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename) Also, please tell us on which OS your are working (Windows, Linux, MS-DOS)

Comment: I think you want to utilize a wide character stream. Please look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789273/read-write-unicode-c

Comment: @ChristopherCrowe not necessarily if file is UTF8 encoded

Comment: Please post relevant part of your code

Comment: Detection will only be possible if [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is present in the file. Otherwise - heuristic methods

Comment: I have updated the question with examples

Comment: @mbaros Why don't you want to show us your code? Is it protected IP?

Comment: These are really two distinct questions, with separate answers. **(1)** [how to use Unicode file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename), and **(2)** How to read the text. That last answer depends on how your text file is encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has natively a pretty good support for unicode, at least for the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), since at least Windows 3 with the Unicode part of the API.

You just have to use wide characters for the name of the file **and** for the functions that process it, and a wide character stream. But without seeing your code, I'm afraid I cannot say much more, except that with decently recent C++ compilers, you can do that either with WinAPI functions or with the standard C++ library (std::wstring and and std::wfstream). But you will have to know what encoding you use for the files...

Comment: Using wstring and wchar_t with fstream (not wfstream) worked well for me