# std::wstring (from wifstream), spec. chars

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, wstring, wifstream

I need a std::wstring, from a std::wifstream, as the wifstream contains, special characters, such as:
    ä,ê

and, so on.

I have a code

```
wifstream *inFile = new wifstream(szFile);

std::wstring szwFileStr((std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(*inFile)),std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
```

but, it does not read in special characters, as I am hoping it would

E.G., the file contains characters, such as ä, and ê, and they turn out as

```
Ã¶
```

I think, the in file, is UTF-8.

Any ideas, some one? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274910/does-wifstream-support-different-encodings

Comment: Possible duplicate: [read unicode file into wstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-file-into-wstring)