# POSIX locale for different unicode scripts to use with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, setlocale

I am using Boost Ofstream for Unicode std::string output. I am stuck with using the right locale (Boost)/ Encoding to support all the languages (in all the Unicode versions upto 6.3). The code is targeted to compile on both VS2010 and GCC 4.8

```
loc::generator gen;
std::locale _loc= gen.generate("en_US.utf-8"); // use the right POSIX locale/ encoding, 
                                              // to support different versions of Unicode 
                                             // and with different compilers
std::string str = "my unicode string";
boost::filesystem::ofstream _file("my file.txt");
_file.imbue(_loc);
_file<<str;
```

I am trying to understand the different Unicode versions, encodings, locale support from different compilers.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to write unicode strings to a file in Windows(VS2010) and Linux (GCC)?

Comment: Usually you can just write the bytes directly into it (as does the sample code in the answer). You need to be way more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: The above code writes "Tésting!" but not "ऐकअ". It writes "???" instead.Is the problem with the compiler setting or std::string or locale for Boost? Can you explain if the POSIX locale format ([language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]]) have any effect for different unicode script.

Comment: Bytes. Bytes. Look at the bytes. Don't look at it through a flawed lens like a text editor. You cannot know if the editor is interpreting the data correctly.

Comment: For the string "ऐकअ", the Bytes read 0x22 3F 3F 3F 22 which is ASCII equivalent of "???". Whereas the Unicode Byte values as per Unicode 6.3 are ऐ : 0x090E;क : 0x0915;अ : 0x0905.i.e, 6 Bytes in total. The problem is with string literals

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1275260/2508038).
also, use wofstream instead of ofstream