# How to apply <cctype> functions on text files with different encoding in c++

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, character-encoding, locale

I would like to Split some files (around 1000) into words and remove numbers and punctuation. I will then process these tokenized words accordingly... However, the files are *mostly* in German language and are encoded in different types:

- ISO-8859-1
- ISO Latin-1
- ASCII
- UTF-8

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot find a correct way to apply [Character Conversion functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/) such as `tolower()` and I also get some weird icons in the terminal when I use `std::cout` at `Ubuntu linux`.

For example, in non UTF-8 files, the word `französische` is shown as `franz�sische`, `für` as
`f�r` etc... Also, words like `Örebro` or `Österreich` are ignored by `tolower()`. From what I know the `"Unicode replacement character" � (U+FFFD)` is inserted for any character that the program cannot decode correctly when trying to handle Unicode.

When I open UTF-8 files i dont get any weird characters but i still cannot convert upper case special characters such as `Ö` to lower case... I used `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.iso88591");` and some other options that I have found on stackoverflow but I still dont get the desired output.

My guess on how I should solve this is:

1. Check encoding of file that is about to be opened
2. open file according to its specific encoding
3. Convert file input to UTF-8
4. Process file and apply `tolower()` etc

Is the above `algorithm` feasible or the complexity will skyrocket?

What is the correct approach for this problem? How can I open the files with some sort of encoding options?

**1. Should my OS have the corresponding locale enabled as global variable to process (without bothering how console displays it)  text?** (in linux for example I do not have de_DE enabled when i use `-locale -a`)

**2. Is this problem only visible due to terminal default encoding? Do I need to take any further steps before i process the extracted string normally in c++?**

My linux locale:

```cpp
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

C
C.UTF-8
el_GR.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Here is some sample code that I wrote that doesnt work as I want atm.

```cpp
void processFiles() {
    std::string filename = "17454-8.txt";
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename);
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //calculate file size
    std::string s = "";
    s.reserve(filesize(filename) + std::ifstream::pos_type(1));
    std::string line;
    while( (inFile.good()) && std::getline(inFile, line) ) {
        s.append(line + "\n");
    }
    inFile.close();

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    //remove punctuation, numbers, tolower,
    //TODO encoding detection and specific transformation (cannot catch Ö, Ä etc) will add too much complexity...
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.iso88591");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (std::ispunct(s[i]) || std::isdigit(s[i]))
            s[i] = ' ';
        if (std::isupper(s[i]))
            s[i]=std::tolower(s[i]);
    }
    //std::cout << s << std::endl;
    //tokenize string
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    tokens.clear();
    tokens = {std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}, std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}};
    for (auto & i : tokens)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        //PROCESS TOKENS
    return;
}
```

Comment: @Incomputable Not really. Will `std::tolower(c, std::locale("en_US.utf8"))` work correctly no matter what the input encoding is?

Comment: @Incomputable The problem now is how am I going to check if a letter `isupper()` in order to apply `s[i] = std::tolower(s[i], std::locale("en_US.utf8"));` ? I somehow have to know the encoding of the file beforehand.

Comment: @Incomputable I would still have to recognize the encoding and then rename the file but that would change the original name of the file, which may not be appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168443/discussion-between-incomputable-and-bugshotgg).

Comment: "Somehow have to know the encoding of the file beforehand": Yes, that is fundamental to using computerized text, always has been and always will be. "Knowing" can come from a communication (e.g. HTTP Content-Type header with the charset field), convention, specification, or standard (particularly for text types like JSON, HTML, and XML). Decades ago there was the convention that all text files on a system would use the encoding chosen by the system administrator. If you can't recover the lost information, you can use some knowledge of the expected context to determine the most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode defines "code points" for characters. A *code point* is a 32 bit value.

There are some types of encodings. ASCII only uses 7 bits, which gives 128 different chars. The 8th bit was used by Microsoft to define another 128 chars, depending on the locale, and called "code pages". Nowadays MS uses UTF-16 2 bytes encoding. Because this is not enough for the whole Unicode set, UTF-16 is also locale dependant, with names that match Unicode's names "Latin-1",  or "ISO-8859-1" etc.

Most used in Linux (typically for files) is UTF-8, which uses a **variable number of bytes** for each character. The first 128 chars are exactly the same as ASCII chars, with just one byte per character. To represent a character UTF8 can use up to 4 bytes. More onfo in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

While MS uses UTF-16 for both files and RAM, Linux likely uses UFT-32 for RAM.

In order to read a file you need to know its encoding. Trying to detect it is a real nightmare which may not succeed. The use of [std::basic_ios::imbue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) allows you to set the desired locale for your stream, like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208431/3871028)

[tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) and such functions can work with a locale, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    wchar_t s = L'\u00D6'; //latin capital 'o' with diaeresis, decimal 214
    wchar_t sL = std::tolower(s, std::locale("en_US.UTF-8")); //hex= 00F6, dec= 246
    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sL= " << sL << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
s = 214
sL= 246
```

In this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275260/3871028) you can find good solutions, as the use of [iconv Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [iconv W32](https://github.com/win-iconv/win-iconv) library.

In Linux the terminal can be set to use a locale with the help of `LC_ALL`, `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`, e.g.:

```
//Deutsch
LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_DE:de:en_US:en"

//English 
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but could you be a bit more specific regarding my code? How should my code be modified for example? I used some proposals from SO and I still cannot make `Ö` work with `tolower()`.

Comment: Updated with a `tolower` sample.