# Why does wide file-stream in C++ narrow written data by default?

Tags: c++, file, unicode, wofstream

Honestly, I just don't get the following design decision in C++ Standard library. When writing wide characters to a file, the `wofstream` converts `wchar_t` into `char` characters:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    wstring someString = L"Hello StackOverflow!";
    wofstream file(L"Test.txt");

    file << someString; // the output file will consist of ASCII characters!
}
```

I am aware that this has to do with the standard `codecvt`. There is `codecvt` for `utf8` in [`Boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html). Also, there is a `codecvt` for `utf16` by [Martin York here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207662/writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode/208431#208431). The question is *why* the `standard codecvt` converts wide-characters? why not write the characters as they are!

Also, are we gonna get real `unicode streams` with C++0x or am I missing something here?

Comment: Good question. I hope you can dig up an answer. Personally I'm leaning towards the "IOStreams is just a badly designed library" theory... ;) It probably doesn't help that Unicode wasn't exactly well established when the library was designed. They might have thought that serializing to/from plain chars was the most portable approach.

Comment: @jalf Thanks. I am not really proficient with streams but this question bothers me a lot :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The model used by C++ for charsets is inherited from C, and so dates back to at least 1989.

Two main points:

- IO is done in term of char.
- it is the job of the locale to determine how wide chars are serialized
- the default locale (named "C") is very minimal (I don't remember the constraints from the standard, here it is able to handle only 7-bit ASCII as narrow and wide character set).
- there is an environment determined locale named ""

So to get anything, you have to set the locale.

If I use the simple program

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t c = 0x00FF;
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    std::wofstream os("test.dat");
    os << c << std::endl;
    if (!os) {
        std::cout << "Output failed\n";
    }
}
```

which use the environment locale and output the wide character of code 0x00FF to a file.  If I ask to use the "C" locale, I get

```
$ env LC_ALL=C ./a.out
Output failed
```

the locale has been unable to handle the wide character and we get notified of the problem as the IO failed.  If I run ask an UTF-8 locale, I get

```
$ env LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ./a.out
$ od -t x1 test.dat
0000000 c3 bf 0a
0000003
```

(od -t x1 just dump the file represented in hex), exactly what I expect for an UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: I bet the output failed because it was expecting another character. And the second one is not what I would expect. unless it is completely ignoring the high bits of the wchar_t. What happens if you output c = 0xABCD; Is it encoding the CD into UTF-8 and ignoring the AB? or is the whole thing encoded. What happens when the UTF-8 character is three bytes long?

Comment: Also I get different results. C: (ff 0a)  en_US.utf8: (std::runtime_error[locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid])

Comment: I don't understand why C3 BF isn't the encoding of 0x00FF you where expecting.  And for 0xABCD it gives EA AF 8D which is what I expected.  What I didn't expect is that it allowed 0xDCBA (it is a surrogate and not a valid code point) and other invalid code points.

Comment: Locale name are not standardized..., so you'd need to find out if you have an utf-8 locale and what is its name and how to set it (under posix, running locale -a in the shell gives you a list).  I don't have time now to find out what are the constraints on the "C" locale for wide characters -- I guess it is implementation defined.

Comment: OK. So it is converting UCS-2 (internal fixed width format) into UTF-8 (External multibyte format). That makes some sense. Note: UCS-2 does not support surrogate pairs (it just encodes them as code points so there is not loss of information when transforming between UTF-16 and UCS-2).

Answer (score 13):

A very partial answer for the first question: A file *is* a sequence of bytes so, when dealing with `wchar_t`'s, at least *some* conversion between `wchar_t` and `char` must occur. Making this conversion "intelligently" requires knowledge of the character encodings, so this is why this conversion is allowed to be locale-dependent, by virtue of using a facet in the stream's locale.

Then, the question is how that conversion should be made in the only locale required by the standard: the "classic" one. There is no "right" answer for that, and the standard is thus very vague about it. I understand from your question that you assume that blindly casting (or memcpy()-ing) between wchar_t[] and char[] would have been a good way. This is not unreasonable, and is in fact what is (or at least was) done in some implementations.

Another POV would be that, since a codecvt is a locale facet, it is reasonable to expect that the conversion is made using the "locale's encoding" (I'm handwavy here, as the concept is pretty fuzzy). For example, one would expect a Turkish locale to use ISO-8859-9, or a Japanese on to use Shift JIS. By similarity, the "classic" locale would convert to this "locale's encoding". Apparently, Microsoft chose to simply trim (which leads to IS-8859-1 if we assuming that `wchar_t` represents UTF-16 and that we stay in the basic multilingual plane), while the Linux implementation I know about decided stick to ASCII.

For your second question:

> Also, are we gonna get real unicode streams with C++0x or am I missing something here?

In the [locale.codecvt] section of n2857 (the latest C++0x draft I have at hand), one can read:

> The specialization `codecvt<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>` converts between the UTF-16 and UTF-8 encodings schemes, and the specialization `codecvt <char32_t, char, mbstate_t>` converts between the UTF-32 and UTF-8 encodings schemes. `codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>` converts between the native character sets for narrow and wide characters.

In the [locale.stdcvt] section, we find:

> For the facet `codecvt_utf8`:
>   — The facet shall convert between UTF-8 multibyte sequences and UCS2 or UCS4 (depending on the size of Elem) within the program.
>   [...]
>
> For the facet `codecvt_utf16`:
>   — The facet shall convert between UTF-16 multibyte sequences and UCS2 or UCS4 (depending on the size of Elem) within the program.
>   [...]
>
> For the facet `codecvt_utf8_utf16`:
>   — The facet shall convert between UTF-8 multibyte sequences and UTF-16 (one or two 16-bit codes) within the program.

So I guess that this means "yes", but you'd have to be more precise about what you mean by "real unicode streams" to be sure.

Comment: @Éric I meant that streams are Unicode aware, as C++0x is. I'm still looking for a rationale answer about the main question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about wofstream. But C++0x will include new distict character types (char16_t, char32_t) of guaranteed width and signedness (unsigned) which can be portably used for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. In addition, there will be new string literals (u"Hello!" for an UTF-16 coded string literal, for example)

Check out the most recent [C++0x draft (N2960)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, this is my guess.

The IOStreams library was constructed under a couple of premises regarding encodings. For converting between Unicode and other not so usual encodings, for example, it's assumed that.

- Inside your program, you should use a (fixed-width) wide-character encoding.
- Only external storage should use (variable-width) multibyte encodings.

I believe that is the reason for the existence of the two template specializations of std::codecvt. One that maps between char types (maybe you're simply working with ASCII) and another that maps between wchar_t (internal to your program) and char (external devices). So whenever you need to perform a conversion to a multibyte encoding you should do it byte-by-byte. Notice that you can write a facet that handles encoding state when you read/write each byte from/to the multibyte encoding.

Thinking this way the behavior of the C++ standard is understandable. After all, you're using wide-character ASCII encoded (assuming this is the default on your platform and you did not switch locales) strings. The "natural" conversion would be to convert each wide-character ASCII character to a ordinary (in this case, one char) ASCII character. (The conversion exists and is straightforward.)

By the way, I'm not sure if you know, but you can avoid this by creating a facet that returns *noconv* for the conversions. Then, you would have your file with wide-characters.

Comment: Your premises will probably not hold. UTF-16 is multibyte. Most people consider UTF-32 to wasteful for character data (I don't) so we will end up using UTF-16 and having all the extra code to handle the special corner case of surrogate pairs.

Comment: @Martin: UTF-8 and UTF-16 are all multibyte. I didn't say they were fixed-width. I don't understand exactly what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
[Class basic_filebuf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8(v=VS.80).aspx)

You can alter the default behavior by setting a *wide* char buffer, using pubsetbuf.
Once you did that, the output will be wchar_t and not char.

In other words for your example you will have:

```
wofstream file(L"Test.txt", ios_base::binary); //binary is important to set!  
wchar_t buffer[128];  
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 128);  
file.put(0xFEFF); //this is the BOM flag, UTF16 needs this, but mirosoft's UNICODE doesn't, so you can skip this line, if any.  
file << someString; // the output file will consist of unicode characters! without the call to pubsetbuf, the out file will be ANSI (current regional settings)
```