# Why does my std::wofstream write ansi?

Tags: c++, stl, wofstream

I've got wide string and I'm writing it to a wofstream that I opened in out|binary mode. When I look in the resultant file, it's missing every other byte.

I was expecting that when I opened the file in visual studio with the binary editor that I'd see every other byte as a zero, but I'm not seeing the zeros.

Do you know what I'm missing?

Thanks.

---

The code is something like this:

```
CAtlStringW data = L"some data";
wofstream stream("c:\hello.txt", ios_base:out|ios_base:binary);
stream.write( data.GetBuffer(), data.GetLength() );
stream.close();
```

Comment: Can you show us some code please

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509277/why-does-wide-file-stream-in-c-narrow-written-data-by-default

Comment: Potential solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207662/writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode/208431#208431

Comment: Short answer: Because the IOstream library is broken. ;)
Wide streams simply take a string of wide characters and convert them to regular char, then write those to the stream. So `L"Hello world"` gets written out as `"Hello world"`. Ridiculous, but true.

Comment: @jaff: No, it isnt. It's designed that way because not all system support unicode on disk, and therefore the standard assumes on-disk formats are in ANSI even if things are unicode internally.

Comment: @BillyONeal Why does it assume that in the first place? shouldn't that be the special case?

Comment: @AraK: Because that's normal behavior -- the vast majority of systems do not recognize wide characters. Furthermore, all interactions on wide characters are implementation defined, and the C++ standard would like files produced on one platform to be usable on other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write to file using output wide stream, what actually happens is that it converts the wide characters to other 8-bit encoding.

If you were using UTF-8 locale it would convert wide strings to UTF-8 encoded text (but MSVC does not provides UTF-8 locales) so generally it would try to convert to some code-page like cp1251 or to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

see the "Community Content" at the bottom of the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1d6b0fk(VS.80).aspx. In short, you have to use pubsetbuf() to use a wchar_t based internal buffer for your stream (instead of a char based).