# Reading in Russian characters (Unicode) using a basic_ifstream<wchar_t>

Tags: c++, locale, ifstream

Is this even possible?  I've been trying to read a simple file that contains Russian, and it's clearly not working.

I've called file.imbue(loc) (and at this point, loc is correct, Russian_Russia.1251).
And buf is of type basic_string<wchar_t>

The reason I'm using basic_ifstream<wchar_t> is because this is a template (so technically, basic_ifstream<T>, but in this case, T=wchar_t).

This all works perfectly with english characters...

```
while (file >> ch)
{
    if(isalnum(ch, loc))
    {
        buf += ch;
    }
    else if(!buf.empty())
    {
        // Do stuff with buf.
        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

I don't see why I'm getting garbage when reading Russian characters.  (for example, if the file contains хеы хеы хеы, I get "яюE", 5(square), K(square), etc...

Comment: Oh the lovely problematic streams in C++ :) Maybe this can give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509277/why-does-wide-file-stream-in-c-narrow-written-data-by-default

Comment: So there really isn't a way that will allow use of templated streams?  This seems far too complicated the way I'm looking at it.  There is no way to have a stream read a particular kind of character at all?

Comment: Firstly, "хеы хеы хеы" is definitely not Russian (although having Russian chars in it). Then, could you make make your example "complete" and provide a link to a sample file (in this case I'll be glad to try helping you).

Comment: Ah, NU UDACHI TOGDA, then :))

Answer (score 1):

Code page 1251 isn't for Unicode -- if memory serves, it's for 8859-5. Unfortunately, chances are that your iostream implementation doesn't support UTF-16 "out of the box." This is a bit strange, since doing so would just involve passing the data through un-changed, but most still don't support it. For what it's worth, at least if I recall correctly, C++ 0x is supposed to add this.

Comment: So, std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t> just cannot be done?  Then why does it exist?  Forgive the nature of my questions, I just don't see a way, at all, to read multibyte characters using streams, and have them be anything but garbage as soon as they're read, unless you write code specifically for each kind of multibyte encoding - which defeats the point of templates altogether.

Comment: @Mark:  The important point here is that your input isn't Unicode.  Is your implementation expecting Unicode?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean - all I know is that the file will be in either ASCII or Unicode (and it's supposed to be selectable at compile time whether or not to use wide or narrow characters - using a template).

Comment: basic_[io]stream<wchar_t> can be done, but most implementations assume the external encoding will be something like ISO 8859-x or shift JIS rather than Unicode. Though they didn't really plan it that way, it's possible to make them read/write files in UTF-8 encoded Unicode. Getting it to work with UTF-16 or UTF-32/UCS-4 would be more difficult. Given that you're doing different transformations with each, at some point you need unique code for each encoding. The template reduces unnecessary duplication elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are still lots of STL implementations that don't have a std::codecvt that can handle Unicode encodings.  Their wchar_t templated streams will default to the system code page, even though they are otherwise Unicode enabled for, say, the filename.  If the file actually contains UTF-8, they'll produce junk.  Maybe [this will help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Iostreams, by default, assumes any data on disk is in a non-unicode format, for compatibility with existing programs that do not handle unicode. C++0x will fix this by allowing native unicode support, but at this time there is a `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>` used by iostreams to convert the normal char data into wide characters for you. See cplusplus.com's [description of std::codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/codecvt/).

If you want to use unicode with iostreams, you need to specify a codecvt facet with the form `std::codecvt<wchar_t, wchar_t, mbstate_t>`, which just passes through data unchanged.

Comment: You just pass the facet to basic_istream<wchar_t>::use_facet, like you would with any other facet.

Comment: I'm not sure that exists...  Maybe I'm misunderstanding how facets work, but I don't see how you could pass one to use_facet, since I don't think use_facet is defined for basic_ifstream.  I could be wrong...

Comment: Sorry -- I'm not very familiar with this stuff :( I think the method you're looking for is `std::basic_ifstream<t>::imbue`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try to call setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

Comment: Err.. no, that's the default locale in any case.