# Can't read unicode (japanese) from a file

Tags: c++, internationalization, character-encoding, cjk

Hi I have a file containing japanese text, saved as unicode file.

I need to read from the file and display the information to the stardard output.

I am using Visual studio 2008

```
int main()   
{  
      wstring line;  
      wifstream myfile("D:\sample.txt"); //file containing japanese characters, saved as unicode file  
      //myfile.imbue(locale("Japanese_Japan"));  
      if(!myfile)  
            cout<<"While opening a file an error is encountered"<<endl;  
      else  
            cout << "File is successfully opened" << endl;  
      //wcout.imbue (locale("Japanese_Japan"));  
      while ( myfile.good() )  
      {  
            getline(myfile,line);  
            wcout << line << endl;  
      }  
      myfile.close();  
      system("PAUSE");  
      return 0;  
}
```

This program generates some random output and I don't see any japanese text on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

Oh boy. Welcome to the Fun, Fun world of character encodings.

The first thing you need to know is that your console is not unicode on windows. The only way you'll ever see Japanese characters in a console application is if you [set your non-unicode (ANSI) locale](http://www.computertipsfree.com/changing-system-locale-language-to-run-non-unicode-programs/) to Japanese. Which will also make backslashes look like yen symbols and break paths containing european accented characters for programs using the ANSI Windows API (which was *supposed* to have been deprecated when Windows XP came around, but people still use to this day...)

So first thing you'll want to do is build a GUI program instead. But I'll leave that as an exercise to the interested reader.

Second, there are a *lot* of ways to represent text. You first need to figure out the encoding in use. Is is UTF-8? UTF-16 (and if so, little or big endian?) Shift-JIS? EUC-JP? You can only use a `wstream` to read directly if the file is in little-endian UTF-16. And even then you need to [futz with its internal buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8(v=VS.80).aspx). Anything other than UTF-16 and you'll get unreadable junk. And this is all only the case on Windows as well! Other OSes may have a different `wstream` representation. It's best not to use `wstream`s at all really.

So, let's assume it's *not* UTF-16 (for full generality). In this case you must read it as a char stream - *not* using a `wstream`. You must then convert this character string into UTF-16 (assuming you're using windows! Other OSes tend to use UTF-8 `char*`s). On windows this can be done with [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx). Make sure you pass in the right code page value, and `CP_ACP` or `CP_OEMCP` are almost always the wrong answer.

Now, you may be wondering how to determine which code page (ie, character encoding) is correct. The short answer is *you don't*. There is no prima facie way of looking at a text string and saying which encoding it is. Sure, there may be hints - eg, if you see a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), chances are it's whatever variant of unicode makes that mark. But in general, you have to be told by the user, or make an attempt to guess, relying on the user to correct you if you're wrong, or you have to select a fixed character set and don't attempt to support any others.

Comment: Well, actually the console is unicode if you set a truetype font, but support for CJK chars is not enabled unless you set the appropriate default system locale.

Comment: @Yuhong, the character encoding used for the windows console is always the non-unicode system locale (aka ANSI aka CP_ACP). It is never UTF-16, UTF-8, or any other unicode locale. The existence of a unicode translation table in the font you choose does not make the console itself unicode compatible.

Comment: Actually, it is the OEMCP, not the ACP that is the main non-Unicode encoding for the console.

Answer (score 0):

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464216/reading-in-russian-characters-unicode-using-a-basic-ifstreamwchar-t) had the same problem with Russian characters (He's using basic_ifstream<wchar_t> wich should be the same as wifstream according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5w4311(v=vs.80).aspx)). In the comments of that question they also link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509277/why-does-wide-file-stream-in-c-narrow-written-data-by-default) which should help you further.

If understood everything correctly, it seems that wifstream reads the characters correctly but your program tries to convert them to whatever locale your program is running in.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

```
std::wifstream(L"D:\\sample.txt");
```

And do not mix `cout` and `wcout`.

Also check that your file is encoded in UTF-16, Little-Endian. If not so, you will be in trouble reading it.

Answer (score -1):

wfstream uses wfilebuf for the actual reading and writing of the data. wfilebuf defaults to using a char buffer internally which means that the text in the file is assumed narrow, and converted to wide before you see it. Since the text was actually wide, you get a mess.

The solution is to replace the wfilebuf buffer with a wide one.

You probably also need to open the file as binary.

```
const size_t bufsize = 128;
wchar_t buffer[bufsize];
wifstream myfile("D:\\sample.txt", ios::binary);
myfile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 128);
```

Make sure the buffer outlives the stream object!

See details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Actually, wfstream uses a basic_filebuf specialized on wchar_t already - and, in fact, `pubsetbuf` would _fail_ if this were not the case. So this code does nothing other than to shrink the buffer to 128 wide characters.

Comment: @bdonlan wfstream uses wfilebuf which is basic_filebuf<wchar_t>. Which defaults to using a char buffer as is explained in the link I provided.