# Unable to write a std::wstring into wofstream

Tags: c++, qt4, wstring, wofstream

I'm using Qt/C++ on a Linux system. I need to convert a `QLineEdit`'s text to `std::wstring` and write it into a `std::wofstream`. It works correctly for ascii strings, but when I enter any other character (Arabic or Uzbek) there is nothing written in the file. (size of file is 0 bytes).

this is my code:

```
wofstream customersFile;
customersFile.open("./customers.txt");
std::wstring ws = lne_address_customer->text().toStdWString();
customersFile << ws << ws.length() << std::endl;
```

Output for `John Smith` entered in the line edit is `John Smith10`. but for unicode strings, nothing.

First I thought that is a problem with `QString::toStdWString()`, but `customersFile << ws.length();` writes correct length of all strings. So I guess I'm doing something wrong wrong with writing `wstring` in file. [?]

EDIT:

I write it again in eclipse. and compiled it with g++4.5. result is same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "" << endl; // prints
   wstring ws = L"سلام"; // this is an Arabic "Hello"
   wofstream wf("new.txt");
   if (!wf.bad())
      wf << ws;
   else
      cerr << "some problem";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee, could you please add std::endl at end of last line: `customersFile << ws << ws.length() << std::endl` just to ensure that flush has been done

Comment: @Dewfy: Ok but nothing is changed...

Comment: What are the status flags on customersFile?  Is customersFile imbued with a locale supporting unicode?

Comment: @AProgrammer: How do i check flags? I just checked if file `is_opened()` or not.

Comment: @Sorush, rdstate(), fail(), bad(), eof()... they should indicates you if there was an error.  If it is the case, the root cause is probably having not set the locale correctly.

Comment: @AProgrammer: All of them are false.

Comment: @Sorush, See if you can write a simple (without QT) standalone program reproducing the problem.  If so, post it here.

Comment: @AProgrammer: I added Qt-less code. Anything changed.... I'm really confused. if I can't use `wofstream` with unicode, why it exist? :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add

```
#include <locale>
```

and at the start of main,

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

Comment: as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509277/why-does-wide-file-stream-in-c-narrow-written-data-by-default?rq=1) this is 'environment determined locale'. A somewhat more generic solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859020/windows-unicode-c-stream-output-failure/9869272#9869272)

Comment: you can set locale directly like : std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));