# c++ wcout stops outputting, also wofstream stops outputting after some calls

Tags: c++, wofstream

I tried to output contents to a file

```
  std::locale::global(std::locale());
  std::wofstream file(outfilename , std::wofstream::binary);

  for (const auto & j : grid[0]) {
      try {
          std::wcout << L"String in WideString " << decoder->decode(j) << std::endl;
          file << decoder->decode(j) << std::endl;
      }
      catch (std::exception& e) {
          std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
      }

  }
```

wcout stops outputting anything ( even "String in WideString" is not outputted ) after some amount of calls,

(I debugged it and it executes wcout like supposed to, after it stopped outputting text)

wofstream also stops outputting after the same amount of calls.

This is the first time I used the widestrings, streams and couts.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: The main suspects are either `decoder`, `grid`, or `grid[0]`, or one of the `j`s being invalid; or `decode` doing something undefined.

Comment: when i normal cout those characters, this cout will output, with the same j and grid

Comment: also when I leave out my own decoder the same happens

Comment: it only stops working when I resort to wcout and wofstream for the file stream

Comment: this is working fine for me and as stated by @molbdnilo issue seems to be with decode or grid https://repl.it/repls/PolishedEmptyActivemovie

Comment: As is the nature of undefined behaviour, the root cause may of course also be located somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Hmm, I am using the string directly if i don use my own encode function... Than it  must have to do something with grid, but the characters are all put out with cout on the same grid, strange. Is there a certain character that can break wcout?

Comment: this is the character, after which nothing works anymore "â‚¬"

Comment: This helped me: [Windows Unicode C++ Stream Output Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859020/windows-unicode-c-stream-output-failure)

Answer (score 1):

it is the € sign, that stops wcout and wofstream from working, removing that from the input file, I get the data from, makes everything work like expected, very strange

Comment: Even stranger, when testing outputting the € sign before, no problems arose, only after using it in exactly this context, this error occured.