# Can't write wstring with Russian characters to file

Tags: c++, linux, wstring, wofstream

I'm trying to write wstrings (in Russian) in Linux, in C++ code in the following code:

```
ofstream outWFile;
outWFile.open("input.tab");
outWFile<< WStringToString(w->get_form());
outWFile<<"\t";
outWFile<<WStringToString(w->get_tag());

std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& s)
{
    std::string temp(s.length(),' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp;
}
```

input.tab contents are invalid

I have tried to do what is proposed in stackoverflow including
[Unable to write a std::wstring into wofstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104329/unable-to-write-a-stdwstring-into-wofstream)
However I didn't help. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to write a std::wstring into wofstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104329/unable-to-write-a-stdwstring-into-wofstream)

Comment: Those `ostream<<` should be `outWFile`?

Comment: Your code doesn't show writing to a file at all, only to the standard output.

Comment: How do you expect this code should work? How do you want it to work? What effort did you make to understand your problem before posting this? Did you notice that function `WStringToString` completely spoils non-ASCII content?

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion function is at fault: it will end up messing up all characters that have a code point of 128/256 or larger (depending on your locale).

Use `wcstombs` instead (make sure to use a UTF-8 locale).

Comment: WStringToString is certainly wrong, but it's not clear that that's being used to write to the file. Also I wouldn't recommend relying on locale based conversions like wcstombs, for the reason you mention; you have to ensure the locale is appropriate for your use, and if it's not it has to be changed. This is not reliable or user friendly. Locale based conversions should only be used when you actually want to use the locale encodings, whatever they are (and this is rare IME).

Comment: @bames53: Yes, locales can cause problems. I personally do most of my Linux coding under the assumption (where applicable) that it's used with a UTF-8 locale, as is the case with any modern Linux system, but I guess I could've suggested something less fragile, now that C++ has Unicode tools built-in.

Comment: Yes, I also just assume UTF-8 always for everything and ignore the locale encoding. The only problems occur for people who deserve them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be better using directly the wstring content.

```
outWfile.write(w->get_tag()->data(), w->get_tag()->size()*sizeof(wchar_t));
// I used data() assuming the string and wstring methods are the same?
// Anyhow, get the pointer to wstring's data here.
```