# outputing multibyte string in C++

Tags: c++, multibyte, wofstream

I have a problem with multibyte char strings. I have simplified my problem as below:

```
std::wstring str = L"multıbyte test string";
std::wofstream f;
f.open("F:\\dump.txt");
f << str;
f.close();
```

and the dump file's content is : "mult"

Why does it cuts the remaining part of str altough i have used wstring and wofstream?

Thanks

Comment: Some questions: How large says your OS that the dump file is? How have you checked the contents of the dump file?

Comment: Could the character 'ı' in 'multıbyte' cause any problem?

Answer (score 1):

`wofstream` writes out data using the current locale. The default locale probably does not support the multibyte characters.

See question: [Unable to write a std::wstring into wofstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104329/unable-to-write-a-stdwstring-into-wofstream)

You can get it to output the full string by:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

before writing, however you won't get the characters as unicode on windows, since it doesn't support UTF-8 locales natively.

To do that, you should convert it to a std::string using `WideCharToMultiByte`, and write it out using regular `ofstream`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to imbue the output stream with some locale to get some reasonable `codecvt` facet to do `wchar_t` to `char` conversion. If you have C++11 supporting compiler or Visual Studio 2010 and later, you can use UTF-8 facet ([`codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)):

```
f.imbue(
    std::locale (         // using std::locale constructed from
        std::locale (),   // global locale
                          // and codecvt_utf8 facet
            new std::codecvt_utf8<char, 0x10FFFF,
                static_cast<std::codecvt_mode>(std::consume_header
                    | std::little_endian)>);
```

There is also [`codecvt_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16).