# C++ wstring to file instead of string

Tags: c++, logging, wstring

I have a simple logger class which I tried to turn into accepting and outputting wstrings instead strings.

header:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class CLog 
{
  public:
    CLog(wstring filename);
    ~CLog();
    void WriteString(string uString);
  private:
    fstream m_stream;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include "log.h";

CLog::CLog(wstring uPath) 
{
  m_stream.open(uPath);
}
void CLog::WriteString(string uString)
{
  m_stream << uString.c_str() << endl;
}
CLog::~CLog()
{
  m_stream.close();
}
```

Can anybody suggest what I should use instead of fstream?
I tried using wstringstream, but it did not even have .open to output it to file, so I thought that is the wrong approach.

I would like to keep the behaviour that it immediately writes to a file.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509277/why-does-wide-file-stream-in-c-narrow-written-data-by-default

Comment: The link that you posted is informative, but not something that helps.

Comment: there was the thing you could use - `std::wofstream`

Comment: Wrong, this is the old version of my code that I posted. I thought I was clear on what I want by stating that it should accept wstring, perhaps I should have been even more clear on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use "wofstream" instead of "fstream" now, and it works perfectly.