# Write C++ file with standard ofstream in UCS-2 LE w/o BOM encoding

Tags: c++, file, byte-order-mark, ofstream

When I output a file with standard ofstream it shows ASCII\ANSI encoding in Notepad++ which is I think normal, but I need this in UCS-2 LE w/o BOM. I don't know what I should change in this code - can you help?

It's an message file format(.vmg) with character encoding in UCS-2 LE w/o BOM n thats what i want to create in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
double i,j;
stringstream sstream;
cout<<"Number Start from:";
cin>>i;
cout<<"\nNumber ends in:";
cin>>j;


for(i;i<=j;)
{

sstream <<i<<".vmg";
string ss = sstream.str();

ofstream sout(ss.c_str());
sout<<"BEGIN:VMSG"<<'\n'<<"VERSION:1.1"<<'\n'<<"X-IRMC-STATUS:"<<'\n'<<"X-IRMC-BOX:INBOX"<<'\n'<<"X-NOK-DT:20101224T190106Z"<<'\n'<<"X-MESSAGE-TYPE:SUBMIT"<<'\n'<<"BEGIN:VCARD"<<'\n'<<"VERSION:3.0"<<'\n'<<"N:"<<'\n'<<"TEL:"<<'\n'<<"END:VCARD"<<'\n'<<"BEGIN:VENV"<<'\n'<<"BEGIN:VCARD"<<'\n'<<"VERSION:3.0"<<'\n'<<"N:"<<'\n'<<"TEL:6969"<<'\n'<<"END:VCARD"<<'\n'<<"BEGIN:VENV"<<'\n'<<"BEGIN:VBODY"<<'\n'<<"Date:24.12.2010 19:01:06"<<'\n'<<"bid "<<i<<'\n'<<"END:VBODY"<<'\n'<<"END:VENV"<<'\n'<<"END:VENV"<<'\n'<<"END:VMSG"<<endl;
sstream.str("");
i=i+0.01;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably include '`<< endl`' in the output line.  What you are seeking is platform dependent.  The mention of Notepad++ suggest Windows, as does UCS-2 LE (probably should be UTF-16LE, though they are basically the same thing).  You are likely to need to look in the manuals.  It may not be possible; if it is, you are likely to need to turn on wide-character encoding, and using a wide-string literal (`L"Hello World"`) would help, not hinder.

Comment: What's with this incessant urge to *not* write a BOM to allow another program that reads the file to guess the encoding correctly?  Why don't you use EBCDIC?

Comment: Actually my desired character encoding of output file is:UCS-2 LE w/o BOM.converting string to stream doesn't help nor L"Hello World" does.And what about EBCDIC,how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

C++ `std::string`s have no explicit encoding (they are just containers of `char`).

You need to determine a couple of things:

- The encoding used internally.
- The encoding used externally.

Then you will know how you can convert between the two.

It is useful to pick a fixed width internal representation, like `UTF-16` or `UTF-32` (I know technically `UTF-16` is not fixed width but `UCS-2` is and it's close enough).

The external representation need not be fixed width but you seem to want UCS-2 (UTF-16). So if you pick an internal format that *matches the external format* then no translation is required and you just spew the string to the stream.

If there is a discrepancy between your internal and external representation (**Like LE -> BE**) you need to convert between the two. To do this use the `codecvt` facet and `imbue` the file stream with an appropriate `locale`. Instructions can be found here: [writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207662/writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode/208431#208431)

#### Edit:

You know the *internal* encoding (since you made a choice).

External encoding: That will depend on the file:

If you created the file, you will know its encoding. If another program created the file you may have to work out the encoding. For example by reading the [`BOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Byte Order mark) at the beginning of the file. That way you can tell if it is `UTF-8`, `UTF-16LE`, `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-32`.

If it is some other encoding, it may be harder to try and work it out or you just have to take a guess.

Comment: I am not sure about what are you asking of internal/external encoding.n how to know if there is a descripency? I added my source code please see above.And thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank you Martin York,but now i know that it's internal encoding then how should i go with the coding?? i have no idea.Your given link doesn't seem to justify to it's title with output though.