# Seeking istreambuf_iterator <wchar_t> clarifications, reading a complete text file of Unicode characters

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring, istream-iterator, wifstream

In the book “Effective STL” by Scott Meyers, there is a nice example of reading an entire text file into a std::string object:

```
std::string sData; 

/*** Open the file for reading, binary mode ***/
std::ifstream ifFile (“MyFile.txt”, std::ios_base::binary); // Open for input, binary mode

/*** Read in all the data from the file into one string object ***/
sData.assign (std::istreambuf_iterator <char> (ifFile),
              std::istreambuf_iterator <char> ());
```

Note that it reads it in as 8-byte characters.  This works very well.  Recently though I have need for reading a file containing Unicode text (i.e., two bytes per char).  However, when I try to (naively) change it to read the data from a Unicode text file into a std::wstring object like so:

```
std::wstring wsData; 

/*** Open the file for reading, binary mode ***/
std::wifstream ifFile (“MyFile.txt”, std::ios_base::binary); // Open for input, binary mode

/*** Read in all the data from the file into one string object ***/
wsData.assign (std::istreambuf_iterator <wchar_t> (ifFile),
               std::istreambuf_iterator <wchar_t> ());
```

The string that I get back, while being of wide characters, still has the alternate nulls.  For example, if the file contains the Unicode string “ABC”, the bytes of the file (ignoring the Unicode lead bytes of 0xFF, 0xFE) are:
    <’A’> <0> <’B’> <0> <’C’> <0>

The first code fragment above would correctly result in the following contents of the (char) string:
    sData [0] = ‘A’
    sData [1] = 0x00
    sData [2] = ‘B’
    sData [3] = 0x00
    sData [4] = ‘C’
    sData [5] = 0x00

However, when the second code fragment is run, it undesirably results in the following contents of the (wchar_t) string:
    wsData [0] = L‘A’
    wsData [1] = 0x0000
    wsData [2] = L‘B’
    wsData [3] = 0x0000
    wsData [4] = L‘C’
    wsData [5] = 0x0000

It’s as if the file were still being read byte by byte and then just simply translated into individual wchar_t characters.

I would have thought that the std::istreambuf_iterator, being specialized to wchar_t , should have resulted in the file being read two bytes at a time, shouldn’t it?  If not, what’s its purpose then?

I have traced into the templates (no easy feat ;-), and the iterator does indeed still seem to be reading the file byte by byte and passing it on to its internal convert routine which dutifully states that conversion is done after each byte (not only after receiving 2 bytes).

I have searched a number of sites on the web  (including this one) for this seemingly trivial task but have not found an explanation of this behavior or a good alternative that does not involve more code than I feel should be necessary (e.g., A Google search of the web produces that same second code fragment as a viable piece of code as well).

The only thing that I have found that works is the following, and I consider that to be a cheat as it needs direct access to the wstring’s internal buffer and then type-coerces it at that.

```
std::wstring wsData; 

/*** Open the file for reading, binary mode ***/
std::wifstream ifFile (“MyFile.txt”, std::ios_base::binary); // Open for input, binary mode

wsData.resize (<Size of file in bytes> / sizeof (wchar_t));

ifFile.read ((char *) &wsData [0], <Size of file in bytes>);
```

Oh, and to forestall the inevitable “Why open the file in binary mode, why not in text mode” question, that open is intentional as if the file was opened in text mode (default), it means that CR/LF ("\r\n" or 0x0D0A) sequences will be converted into just LF ("\n" or 0x0A) sequences, whereas a pure byte read of the file would have preserved them.   Regardless, for those diehards, changing that had, unsurprisingly, no effect.

So two questions here, why does the second case not work as one might expect (i.e., what is going on with those iterators), and what would be your favorite “kosher STL-way” of loading a file of Unicode characters into a wstring?

What am I missing here; it has to be something silly.

Chris

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for writing such a precise and detailed first question!

Answer (score 13):

You must be disppointed with SO to have received no answers to your first question after 
4-and-half-months. It is a good question, and most good questions are answered 
(well or badly) within minutes. Two the likely reasons for the neglect of yours are:

- You did not tag it "C++", so many C++ programmers who might have been able to help will never have
  noticed it. (I have now tagged it "C++".)
- Your question is about unicode stream-handling, which is no-one's idea of cool coding.

The misconception that has thwarted your investigations seems to be this: You appear to 
believe that a wide-character stream, `std::wfstream`, and wide-character string, `std::wstring`, 
are respectively the same as a "unicode stream" and a "unicode string", and specifically that 
they are respectively the same as a UTF-16 stream and a UTF-16 string. Neither of these things is true.

An `std::wifstream` (`std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t>`) is an input stream that converts an 
external sequence of bytes to an internal sequence of `wchar_t`, *according to a specified 
or default encoding of the external sequence*.

Likewise an `std::wofstream` (`std::basic_ofstream<wchar_t>`) is an output stream that 
converts an internal sequence of `wchar_t` to an external sequence of bytes, *according to a 
specified or default encoding of the external sequence*.

And an `std::wstring` (`std::basic_string<wchar_t>`) is a string type that simply stores 
a sequence of `wchar_t`, without knowledge of the encoding - if-any - from which they resulted.

*Unicode* is a family of byte-sequence encodings - UTF-8/-16/-32, and some more obscure others - 
related by the principle that UTF-*N* encodes alphabets using a sequence of 1 or more 
*N*-bit units per symbol. UTF-16 is apparently the encoding you are trying to read 
into a `std::wstring`. You say:

> I would have thought that the std::istreambuf_iterator, being specialized to wchar_t, should have resulted in the file being read two bytes at a time, shouldn't it? If not, what's its purpose then?

But once you know that `wchar_t` is not necessarily 2 bytes wide (it is in Microsoft's C libraries, 
both 32 and 64-bit, but in GCC's it is 4 bytes wide), and also that a UTF-16 code-point (character) 
need not fit into 2 bytes (it can require 4), you will see that that specifying an extraction 
unit of `wchar_t` cannot be all there is to decoding a UTF-16 stream.

When you construct and open your input stream with:

```
std::wifstream ifFile ("MyFile.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
```

It is prepared to extract characters (of some alphabet) from "MyFile.txt" into values 
of type `wchar_t` and it will extract those characters from the byte-sequence in the 
file according to the encoding specified by the [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) 
that is operative on the stream when it does the extracting.

Your code does not specify an `std::locale` for your stream, so the library's default takes effect. 
That default is the global C++ locale, which in turn by default is the
["C" locale](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/24-1.html); and the "C" locale assumes 
the "identity encoding" of I/O byte sequences, i.e. 1 byte = 1 character (
setting aside the newline exception for text-mode I/O).

Thus, when you employ your `std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>` to 
extract the characters, the extraction proceeds by converting each byte 
in the file to a `wchar_t` which it appends to the `std::wstring wsData`. The bytes 
in the file are, as you say:

0xFF, 0xFE, 'A', 0x00, 'B', 0x00, 'C', 0x00

The first two, which you discount as "unicode lead bytes", are indeed a 
UTF-16 byte-order mark (BOM) but in the default encoding they just are what they are.

Accordingly the wide-characters assigned to `wsData` are, as you observed:

0x00FF, 0x00FE, L'A', 0x0000, L'B', 0x0000, L'C', 0x0000

> It's as if the file were still being read byte by byte and then just simply translated into individual wchar_t characters.

because that it precisely what is happening.

To stop this happening, you need to do something before you start extracting characters from the stream
to tell it that it is supposed to decode a UTF-16 character sequence. The way to do that 
is conceptually rather tortuous. You need to [`imbue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/imbue) 
the stream with an [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) that possesses an 
[`std::locale::facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet) that is an instantiation 
[`std::codecvt<InternT, ExternT, StateT>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) (or is derived from such) 
which will provide the stream with the correct methods from decoding UTF-16 into `wchar_t`.

But the gist of this is that you need to plug the right UTF-16 encoder/decoder into the stream and 
in practice it is (or should be) simple enough. I am guessing that your compiler is a recent MS VC++. 
If that's right, then, you can fix your code by:

- Adding `#include <locale>` and `#include <codecvt>` to your headers
- Adding the line:

  `ifFile.imbue(std::locale(ifFile.getloc(),new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t,0x10ffff,std::little_endian>));`

right after:

```
std::wifstream ifFile ("MyFile.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
```

The effect of this new line is to "imbue" `ifFile` with a new locale that is the same 
as the one it already had - `ifFile.getloc()` - but with a modified encoder/decoder facet
 - `std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t,0x10ffff,std::little_endian>`. This `codecvt` facet is 
one that will decode UTF-16 characters with a maximum value of `0x10ffff` into little-endian 
`wchar_t` values (`0x10ffff` being the maximum value of UTF-16 code-points).

When you debug into the code thus amended you will now find that `wsData` is only 4 wide-characters long
and that those characters are:

`0xFEFF, L'A', L'B', L'C'`

as you expect them to be, with the first one being the UTF-16 little-endian BOM.

Notice that the order `FE`,`FF` is the reverse of what it was before application 
of the `codecvt` facet, showing us that little-endian decoding was done as requested. 
And it needed to be. Just edit the new line by removing `std::little_endian`, 
debug it again, and you will then find that the first element of `wsData` becomes `0xFFFE` 
and that other three wide-characters become pictograms of the 
[IICore](http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~irg/irg/IICore/IICore.htm) pictographic 
character-set (if your debugger can display them). (Now, whenever a colleague 
complains in amazement that their code is turning English Unicode into "Chinese", 
you will know a likely explanation.)

Should you want to populate `wsData` without the leading BOM, you can do that by 
amending the new line again and replacing `std::little_endian` with 
`std::codecvt_mode(std::little_endian|std::consume_header)`

Finally, you may well have noted a bug in the new code, namely that a 2-byte `wchar_t`
is insufficiently wide to represent the UTF-16 code-points between 0x100000  and 0x10ffff 
that could be read.

You will get away with this as long as all the code-points you have to read lie in the 
UTF-16 [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane),
which spans [0,0xffff], and you might know that all inputs will forever obey that 
constraint. Otherwise, a 16-bit `wchar_t` is not fit for purpose. Replace:

- `wchar_t` with `char32_t`
- `std::wstring` with `std::basic_string<char32_t>`
- `std::wifstream` with `std::basic_ifstream<char32_t>`

and the code is fully fit to read an abitrary UTF-16 encoded file into a string.

(Readers who are working with the the GNU C++ library will find that as of v4.7.2 
it does not yet provide the `<codecvt>` standard header. The header `<bits/codecvt.h>` exists and presumbly will sometime graduate to being `<codecvt>`, but at this point it only
exports the specializations `class codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>` and 
`class codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>`, which are respectively the identity 
conversion and the conversion between ASCII/UTF-8 and `wchar_t`. To solve the OP's problem
you need to subclass `std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,std::char_traits<wchar_t>::state_type>` 
yourself, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208431/1362568))

Comment: 16 bit `wchar_t` is fine for UTF-16 code, you just have to remember that each codepoint may take one or more `wchar_t`.  But that's not that big a deal if you also recall that each "glyph" on the screen can be composed of many codepoints anyway.  I'd hardly consider using `wchar_t` in this way a "bug".  Simply nonportable.

Comment: I've experimented with this and still have to disagree. Take the 2-unit codepoint U+1D11E (the G-clef). This will be UTF-16LE encoded in a file containing `FF FE 34 D8 1E DD`. Read this file in the manner of my fix (with `std::consume_header`, built with MS VC++ 2012) *but* keep the stream and string instantiated for `wchar_t`. Then `wsData` ends up with length 1 and `wsData[0]` is `d11e`. The first code unit has been lost. Replace `wchar_t` with `char32_t` then we get `1d11e`, correctly. Don't know whether the MS library is buggy here, but anyway we corrupt the data with `wchar_t`.

Comment: Er, yeah, that would be a bug in the MS library.  I am pretty sure it should not be doing that.

Comment: Wait, according to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16) that behavior is per spec!  WTF!

Comment: Right, we're both the wiser for Chris Weiner's first question :)

Comment: Ouch!  I really must appologize for not checking back here.  The question reamained unanswered for so long that I let it fade into memory.  It was only my chance finding of this article (in another site, sorry) [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4563/Upgrading-an-STL-based-application-to-use-Unicode) that caused me to remember this question and look back (surprisingly I never got a notification that an answer was even posted :-(   Thanks Mike and Mooing for your information and to a level of detail above and beyond the call of duty!

Comment: @ChrisWiesner. You're welcome. It was most unusual for your question to be ignored for so long. Should you wish to mark my answer as accepted, how to do so is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/196691)

Comment: +n This answer absolutely rocks, and I wish I could up-vote it a dozen more times.